# как у полного пути файла узнать только название pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qfiledialog

Делаю приложение, которое открывает *excel* файл. Когда открывается окно, где нужно выбрать файл, после выбора файла переменная принимает весь путь к файлу, а как сделать так, чтобы переменная принимала только название файла.

**main.py**

```
from UI.table import Ui_table
     
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
QStackedWidget, QMessageBox
import openpyxl
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import pandas as pd 


class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table):


def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self) 
    self.initUI()
    
def initUI(self):
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

def update(self):
    self.textBrowser.clear()
    wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="fname", data_only=True)
    print(wb.sheetnames)
    wb.active = 0
    sheet = wb.active
    row_count = sheet.max_row # нахождение строк в excel
    #column_count = sheet.max_column # нахождение столбцов в excel
    for i in range(1,row_count+1):

        table = (sheet['A'+str(i)].value,sheet['B'+str(i)].value,sheet['C'+str(i)].value)
        print(table)
        self.textBrowser.append(str(table))


def open_file(self):
    global fname
    fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', 'c:\\',
        "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)",'/home')
        

if __name__ == '__main__': 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()

windows = QStackedWidget()

windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  # 0
windows.setWindowTitle("")

windows.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`

**table.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_table(object):
 def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
    self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 140, 581, 401))
    self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 131, 31))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.action.setObjectName("action")
    self.menu.addAction(self.action)
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 
    4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; 
    font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin- 
    right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "обновить"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
    self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
    self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть файл"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Глобальные переменные - это ЗЛО.
2. Результат `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()` - кортеж.

---

```
import sys
import openpyxl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QStackedWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd 

# from UI.table import Ui_table
class Ui_table(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 140, 581, 401))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML \
        4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; \
        font-style:normal;\">\n"
        "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-\
        right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "обновить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "открыть файл"))


class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.fname = None                                                             # +++
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

    def update(self):
        if not self.fname:                                                             # +++
            return                                                                     # +++
    
        self.textBrowser.clear()

        #                                                 vvvvvvvvvv <---------------  # +++
        wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename=self.fname, data_only=True)  # +++ 
       
        print(wb.sheetnames)
        wb.active = 0
        sheet = wb.active
        row_count = sheet.max_row # нахождение строк в excel
        #column_count = sheet.max_column # нахождение столбцов в excel
        for i in range(1,row_count+1):
            table = (sheet['A'+str(i)].value,sheet['B'+str(i)].value,sheet['C'+str(i)].value)
            print(table)
            self.textBrowser.append(str(table))

    def open_file(self):
#        global fname   # НЕТ

#                 vvv <---                                                                 # +++
        self.fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', '.',  # +++
            "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)") #,'/home')
        print(f'fname = {self.fname}')    
        

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()
    windows = QStackedWidget()
    windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  # 0
    windows.setWindowTitle("QStackedWidget")

    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

`os.path.basename(fullpath)`

Этж питон, тут всё есть из коробки